# Adding a PaperClip to attach Images

Tags: android, camera, paperclip, gallery

Actually I want to implement a Functionality where I need to attach a Paperclip, on clicking which I need to display the Options to Attach a Picture from the Local Gallery or take a Picture from Camera and attach it in order to send it to someone.

Can anyone Please tell me how I can do this.

Thanks,
David

Comment: use FragmentLayout for this

Comment: before sending save it and use it

Comment: AM_You are not getting What I asked I think

Comment: okay ... you want a paperclip on the images which yo'll selecte from galaray and camera or otheres

Comment: Not on Images, I have a Button(a Papeerclip) which I need to click to Open Gallery